# Get videos shared by friends on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video

I am trying to extract all videos shared by my friends on Facebook (not only Facebook videos but also videos from other sources like YouTube, Vimeo etc). I have gone through the Facebook Graph API documentation and it only explains a way to extract videos in which the user tagged.

Can I get some pointers/references on how to investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Links shared by users also contain videos. You can traverse through links and find links which conatin youtube.com or vimeo.com. You can use regularexpressions to extract unique youtube ID